# Ruby on Rails Devise Gem Set minimum password length dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic, devise, passwords

Currently I am setting the password length with

```
config.password_length = 6..128
```

but how can I change it dynamically during runtime without restarting the server?

I implemented

```
def password_complexity
```

I could check it in there but then I have to disable the setting in config. How can I disable it?

Comment: Why do you need to change password length requirements dynamically? What is the use-case?

Comment: @spickermann I want to give admins the option to change it.

Comment: Should admins be able to change it for a specific user, a group of users, or globally for all users in the application. Temporarily or permanently?

Comment: @spickermann permanently for a group of users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Validatable module just generates a bunch of Rails validations for you
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/367ea427626ea8d9a8315b296535a4d93f311fab/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L37

Since `:within` doesnt take a symbol or a lambda it seems you either have to do some ugly meta programming to remove the validation rule and replace it with your own or you could just not include the Devise `:validatable` module and set all the validation rules yourself for more fine grained control

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates_length_of :password, minimum: -> (user) { user.password_range.first }, maximum: -> (user) { user.password_range.last }, allow_blank: true
  # other password/email rules

  private
  
  def password_range
    if something?
      (12..250)
    else
      (4..20)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I removed : validatable and set my own validation rules.